# chaining text on text view at list item acceding to item click in another list View

Tags: android, list

i have 2 list views next to each other, both have text views in their items. i need to set the text in the second list to the text of the item the user clicked in the 1st list. the point is to let the user to define an order of something so no matter what item he selects on the 1st list first i need to set the text on the second list of item at position 0 then 1 and so on.

this is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/assaignmentListViewLeft"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/assaignmentListViewRight"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

my adapters:

```
public class ListLeftAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RoomateModel> {

    public Context context;

    public ListLeftAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RoomateModel> items){
        super(context, 0, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.assaignment_list_item_left, parent, false);
        }

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        name.setText("my text");

        return convertView;
    }
```

my 2nd list adapter:

```
public class ListRightAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RoomateModel> {

public Context context;

public ListRightAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RoomateModel> items){
        super(context, 0, items);
        this.context = context;
        }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.assaignment_list_item_right, parent, false);
        }

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        return convertView;
        }
```

my  main activity:

```
public class AddNewAssaignment extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<RoomateModel> list;
    ListLeftAdapter leftAdapter;
    ListRightAdapter rightAdapter;
    ListView lvLeft;
    ListView lvRight;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_assaignment);
        list = new ArrayList<RoomateModel>();
        lvLeft = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.assaignmentListViewLeft);
        lvRight = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.assaignmentListViewRight);
        lvLeft.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // here i need to change the text in the 2nd list view items

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please check Filters.

Comment: Can you please provide your details RoomModel class

Comment: it has name and id fields and getters and setters. i dont see why it matters in my qeustion

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your ArrayList for ListView or some and notifyDataSetChanged only that way you can access previous list items